# Geometric intuition for $R[a^{-1}]$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, localization

The ideal of polynomials vanishing over a point in an affine algebraic variety is maximal, and I think I understand the geometric intuition behind localizing it(s complement).

But what about multiplicative submonoids which are not complements of primes? In particular, what is the geometric intuition behind localizing at $S= \left\{ 1,a,a^2 ,\dots \right\}$?

Along the same line, what is the intuition behind the following fact?

**Fact.** $\sqrt{ \left\langle a \right\rangle}=\sqrt{ \left\langle b \right\rangle  }\implies R[a^{-1}]\cong R[b^{-1}]$

Here $R[a^{-1}]$ denotes localization at $S$.

Comment: Here, you are deleting the vanishing locus of $a$.

Comment: Think through a simple example like $R=k[x]$ and $a=x$. Your fact is a manifestation of the idea that in contrast to closed sets there's only one natural scheme structure on an open subset of a scheme.